# Spring HATEOAS ControllerLinkBuilder removes trailing slash?

Tags: java, spring, spring-hateoas

I am trying to incorporate Spring HATEOAS into an existing service tool and REST API. However, one of the issues I"m encountering is that the ControllerLinkBuilder seems to remove trailing slashes (which is a requirement due to existing constraints). Is there some workaround or method to get that trailing slash added to the link?

```
 user.add(linkTo(UserController.class).slash("user").slash(user.getUsername() + "/").withRel("Get User Details"));
```

(User extends ResourceSupport)

I have also tried .slash("") to no avail.

The output:

```
"http://localhost:8080/REST/user/<username>"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not just using link builder as far as i can see. LinkBuilders use UriComponents to parse it out.  Then it goes through each segment and adds them back into the a UriComponents builder.  **stuff/** goes in the UriComponents but **stuff** is all that comes out.

What you can do is make that a Link in a round about way, eg:

```
user.add(
    new Link(
         linkTo(UserController.class).slash("user").slash(user.getUsername())
            .toUriComponentsBuilder().build().toUriString() + "/",
         "Get User Details"
    )
);
```

there's probably an easier way...but you get the idea.  Link doesn't seem to shove you through the UriComponents stuff

Comment: Thanks for the input, it's helpful. In the end yesterday, I ended up changing the RequestMapping around to require the trailing "/", which worked. This is a good solution to the problem in general, however, so I'm picking it.

Comment: would you mind to share your code. I am hitting the same problem and my endpoints already require a trailing slash `@RequestMapping("/stuff/")` . But ControllerLinkBuilder still doesn't add a trailing slash.

Comment: Any news on a cleaner and quicker way to accomplish this? This doesn't even work (anymore?), the slash is removed again